# Replace missing value with a macro

Tags: macros, sas

As I want to make a macro program to replace multiple variable'missing values by their previous non-missing values within a group and before that I need to sort the dataset using multiple-by variables in order to identify every observations.

I have a test dataset:

```
data temp2;
input countryname $1-5 +1 countrycode $7-8 +1 dev 1. +1 legal 1. +1 audit 1.;
datalines;
china 22 9 2 3
china 22 . . 3
china 22 7 3 .
china 21 4 . .
japan 13 3 . 1
japan 12 3 . .
japan 13 1 2 3
 ;
run;
```

And as you can see, I need to sort by countryname and countrycode. And replace the `dev` `legal` `audit` missing value. I have tried a macro like:

```
`%macro replace(dsetin=,dsetout=,idvars=,vars=);
 %if &dsetout = %then %let dsetout = &dsetin;
 %let char=_;
 %do xi=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&vars));
 %let var = %scan(&vars,&xi);
 %let  _VARs_=%sysfunc(cat(&char,&var));
 %end;
 %let m=%sysfunc(countw(&vars));
 %do yi=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&idvars));
 %let idvar = %scan(&idvars,&yi);
 %let lagid = lag(&idvar);
 %end;
 %let n=%sysfunc(countw(&idvars));
 proc sort data=&dsetin out=temp1;
 by &idvars;
 run;
 data &dsetout;
 set temp1;
 by &idvars;
 array id(&n)&idvar;
 array lag(&n)&lagid;
 array vara(&m)&var;
 array vars(&m)&_VARs_;
 do yi = 1 to &n;
 if lag(yi)=id(yi) then do;
 do xi= 1 to &m;
 retain &_VARs_;
 if not missing(&var) then &_VARs_ =&var;
else &var = &_VARs_; 
end;
%end;
end;
drop of &_VARs_:;
run;
%mend replace;
%replace(dsetin=temp,dsetout=temp2,idvars=countryname countrycode,vars=DEV LEGAL AUDIT)`
```

It seems tedious.
I can not handle the task. Since the number of by-variables using sort may be different from the number of 'replace' variables. I hope the macro can be applied to different occasions. Sometimes the number of idvars using sort can be more than the number of 'replace' variables. Sometimes the former can be less than the latter one.

Hope it can illustrate my problems. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this produces the desired results?

Whenever a variable defined in &vars is missing, it will be replaced with it's own lag.

```
data temp;
    input countryname $1-5 +1 countrycode $7-8 +1 dev 1. +1 legal 1. +1 audit 1.;
    datalines;
china 22 9 2 3
china 22 . . 3
china 22 7 3 .
china 21 4 . .
japan 13 3 . 1
japan 12 3 . .
japan 13 1 2 3
;run;

%macro replace(dsetin,dsetout,idvars,vars);
    %if &dsetout = %then %let dsetout = &dsetin;

    proc sort data=&dsetin out=temp1;
        by &idvars;
    run;

    data &dsetout;
        set temp1;
        *by &idvars;

        array variables &vars;
        array lags {%sysfunc(countw("&vars"))};

        do i=1 to countw("&vars");
            lags[i] = lag(variables[i]);
            if variables[i]=. then variables[i] = lags[i];
        end;

        drop of lags: ;
        drop i;

    run;

%mend replace;
%replace(temp,,countryname countrycode,DEV LEGAL AUDIT);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `UPDATE` statement to carry forward non-missing values.

So we can create this macro that will sort the data and then use UPDATE statement to carry forward the non-missing values of the selected variable. By adding an extra SET statement we can make sure any other variables are not impacted by the UPDATE operation. Finally we need an OUTPUT statement to write every observation, otherwise only the last observation of the BY group would be written.  We can even make it smart enough to update all non-by variables if VARS is left blank.

```
%macro replace(dsetin=,dsetout=,idvars=,vars=);
  %if not %length(&dsetin) %then %let dsetin=&syslast;
  %if not %length(&dsetout) %then %let dsetout=&dsetin ;
  %if %length(&vars) %then %let vars=&idvars &vars;
  proc sort data=&dsetin out=&dsetout;
    by &idvars;
  run;
  data &dsetout ;
    update &dsetout (obs=0) &dsetout (keep=&vars) ;
    by &idvars ;
    set &dsetout(drop=&vars);
    output;
  run;
%mend replace ;
```

Now let's build some test data:

```
data have;
  length countryname $5 countrycode $2 dev legal audit 8 ;
  input countryname -- audit ;
datalines;
china 22 9 2 3
china 22 . . 3
china 22 7 3 .
china 21 4 . .
japan 13 3 . 1
japan 12 3 . .
japan 13 1 2 3
;;;;
```

And run the macro with all variables being retained. And then again with just one.

```
%replace(dsetin=have,dsetout=want1,idvars=countryname countrycode,vars=);
%replace(dsetin=have,dsetout=want2,idvars=countryname countrycode,vars=legal);
```

And then compare the results.

```
proc compare data=want1 compare=want2 ;
run;
```

Comment: thank you ! you have provided a new method.it may help me with future cases.